# How to collapse or expand all RichFaces collapsiblePanel elements on the page?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using RichFaces with JSF to develop a simple app.  One page of this app contains several collapsiblePanel elements.  Some of the collapsiblePanel elements are nested, but never more than a second layer.

I would like to provide links or buttons on the page to expand all and collapse all collapsiblePanel elements on the page.  How can I do that?

The elements currently use the `switchType="client"` attribute to let the client handle the expanding and collapsing.  I suspect that using a type of `ajax` instead may help, but I'm not sure nor do I know how I would take advantage of it.

**Update**:  My question may be easier to understand if I include an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<h:form>
  <a4j:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.setDefaultExpanded(true)}"
                render="reportPanel" value="Expand all" />
  <a4j:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.setDefaultExpanded(false)}"
                render="reportPanel" value="Collapse all" />

  <h:panelGrid id="reportPanel">
    <ui:repeat var="account" value="#{bean.results.entrySet().toArray()}">
      <rich:collapsiblePanel expanded="#{bean.defaultExpanded}">
        <ui:repeat var="chargeGroup" value="#{account.value.entrySet().toArray()}">
          <rich:collapsiblePanel expanded="#{bean.defaultExpanded}">
            <h:outputText value="content: #{chargeGroup.value}" />
          </rich:collapsiblePanel>
        </ui:repeat>
      </rich:collapsiblePanel>
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<rich:collapsiblePanel>` has the `expanded` attribute, you can bind it to bean property and control the expansion from there. Something like this

```
<rich:collapsiblePanel id="panel1" expanded="#{bean.expanded}" …>

<a4j:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.togglePanels()}" 
    … render="panel1, panel2, …"/>
```

The `switchType` controls where the content is pulled from, not how you expand/collapse the panel.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me somewhere to start.  Rather than list all the IDs, I wrapped all of the rich:collapsiblePanel elements inside a single h:panelGrid and used its ID.  I also removed the switchType attributes so the panels would default to the ajax type.  It seemed to work well until I realized that now all the panels must have the same expanded state.  I didn't explain the problem well, I guess.  I meant for the user to be able to expand/collapse any of the panels, with these buttons to expand/collapse all panels.  Does this mean I need to keep the state for each panel?

Comment: I don't think I understand. You have several panels - some expanded and some collapsed - you click the button. What do you want to happen?

Comment: The solution you gave works great if we want to see all collapsiblePanels open or closed.  However, I found that when I clicked a few individual panels open, then clicked the commandButton to open them all, then tried to click a few panels closed, the panels' states in the bean started to get out of sync with their visual states in the UI.  When that happened, sometimes clicking the button to expand them all did nothing at all.  I expected the button to open them all, but it didn't happen.  At that point, if I closed some open panels and *then* clicked the button, then it might work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when click individual panels and then expand/collapse all. This work for me (richfaces 4.2.3):

```
<h:commandButton  immediate="true" action="#{controllerBean.toggleMin}"  value="collapse all" >
    <a4j:ajax render="panel1 panel2"></a4j:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton immediate="true" action="#{controllerBean.toggleMax}" value="expand all">
    <a4j:ajax render="panel1 panel2"></a4j:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
...
<rich:collapsiblePanel id="panel1" immediate="true" expanded="#{modelBean.expanded}" header="Title text" switchType="client">
    ...
</rich:collapsiblePanel>
...
```